# Calling a function changes value of another pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNOME 60

typedef struct Periodo
{
    char nome[MAXNOME];
    struct Periodo *nextPeriodo;
} periodo;

void getNomePeriodo(char *nomePeriodo){

    printf("Type name: ");
    scanf("%s", nomePeriodo);

    return;
}

void getMenuHeader(){
    printf("\n\n");
 }

void insertPeriodo(periodo **basePeriodo){

    periodo novoPeriodo;
    getNomePeriodo(novoPeriodo.nome);
    novoPeriodo.nextPeriodo = NULL;

    periodo *itrPeriodo = *basePeriodo;
    while(itrPeriodo->nextPeriodo!=NULL){
        itrPeriodo = itrPeriodo->nextPeriodo;
    }

    itrPeriodo->nextPeriodo = &novoPeriodo;
    printf("OK!\n");
    return;
}

int main(){
    int *opcaoMenu = malloc(sizeof(int));

    periodo *basePeriodo = malloc(sizeof(periodo));

    insertPeriodo(&basePeriodo);
    printf("%p\n", (basePeriodo)->nextPeriodo->nextPeriodo);
    getMenuHeader();
    printf("%p\n", (basePeriodo)->nextPeriodo->nextPeriodo);
    return 0;
}
```

Basically the problem I'm facing is that it looks like the value of `(basePeriodo)->nextPeriodo->nextPeriodo` is changing when I call the function `getMenuHeader`, the output I am having is this:

```
Type name: 2020
OK!
(nil)


0x7ffe9dd7d840
```

I would expect that the value of `(basePeriodo)->nextPeriodo->nextPeriodo` would be the same independent of the function call and it would be NULL as it is before function but I have no idea why it changes after I call it, could someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: `itrPeriodo->nextPeriodo = &novoPeriodo;` You must take care of the lifetime of `novoPeriodo`. After you leave that function, it does not exist any more and accessing that memory is illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems (at least):

1. The structure `**basePeriodo` is *uninitialized* and its members will be *indeterminate*. That includes the pointer `nextPeriodo` which might not be `NULL`. This will make the loop in `insertPeriodo` maybe iterate out into unallocated memory, leading to *undefined behavior*.
2. When you fix this problem, `novoPeriodo` is a *local* variable inside the `insertPeriodo` function. Once the function returns the life-time of `novoPeriodo` ends and any pointers to `novoPeriodo` will become invalid. That means the assignment

   ```
   itrPeriodo->nextPeriodo = &novoPeriodo;
   ```

   is invalid, and also lead to *undefined behavior* if you use this pointer after the function returns.

   The common solution is to dynamically allocate the node structure.